# rails generate model user is not working using neo4j gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, neo4j

I have stated working on neo4j with rails using the **gem 'neo4j'**, Every thing is working fine except the model generation.
If i will write rails generate model user its not creating the user model. But Rails g controller is working fine.
Does any one have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the Neo4j gem as responsible for this task. In `application.rb`, within the `class Application < Rails::Application` definition, add `config.generators { |g| g.orm :neo4j }`.